# Laravel Custom Request Class - can I define Middleware here?

Tags: laravel, laravel-middleware, laravel-request

So, for me the main 2 methods of adding middleware are in the routes files, `api.php` and `web.php`, or alternatively in the constructor of any `Controller` class.

However it occurred to me that there might be situations where I want to choose for a certain Request subclass to have some middleware applied to it. I haven't seen documentation for this. Is there a way to define middleware in these custom Requests?

For clarity, I'm referring to the Request classes that get made when you do `php artisan make:request`